# Why is this coroutine code not printing anything?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When runBlocking is used the lines are getting printed but in the following case its not printing anything

```
fun main(){
     GlobalScope.launch{
    
        println("function started") //printing the first line
        delay(1000)
        println("function ended")   //printing the last line

}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You program terminates before the launched coroutine has a chance to start.

`launch` starts an asynchronous piece of code, so the program can keep going after calling `launch` without waiting for the body of `launch` to execute. There is nothing in your current code that waits for this coroutine to finish before terminating the program, so the program just ends.

> When runBlocking is used the lines are getting printed

I'm assuming you're referring to running it this way:

```kotlin
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch {
        println("function started") //printing the first line
        delay(1000)
        println("function ended")   //printing the last line
    }
}
```

`runBlocking` here defines a `CoroutineScope` that is available as `this` inside the lambda. The `launch` here is launched in that scope, which makes it a child coroutine of `runBlocking`.

By definition, `runBlocking` blocks the current thread (the main thread here) until all child coroutines are completed. This is why in that case the program waits for the coroutine to complete.

If you're just learning coroutines, you should really avoid using delicate APIs like `GlobalScope`. Instead, try to stick with [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency). Structured concurrency is a way to structure your coroutines with parent-child relations so that you don't get surprised by coroutine leaks (like this one).